# Jmeter maven lighting plugin build failure even though generates output

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm attempting to use jmeter maven lighting plugin to undertake automated report analysis, however I get a build failure. [Lighting](http://automatictester.github.io/lightning/index.html) enables integration of CI/CD with jmeter.

I was able to setup the lighting demo project, however when I do it for my project it will result in a build failure. The error is below:

```
              [ERROR] Failed to execute goal uk.co.automatictester:jmeter- 
              lightning-maven-plugin:1.2.0:lightning (default) on project 
              jmeter-lightning-maven-plugin-example: MojoExecutionException 
             -> [Help 1]
```

However examination of the console log indicates that the rules was applied and a output was generated, however it returned a result based upon the criteria specified in the lighting.xml configuration file.

```
   [DEBUG]   (f) jmeterCsv = 
   C:\Projects\lightingMaven\target\jmeter\results\TestPerformance.csv
   [DEBUG]   (f) mode = verify
   [DEBUG]   (f) testSetXml = 
   C:\Projects\lightingMaven\src\test\resources\lightning.xml
   [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
   [DEBUG] Reading CSV file - start
   [DEBUG] Reading CSV file - finish, read 1602 rows, took 63ms
   [INFO] Test name:            Test #1
   [INFO] Test type:            avgRespTimeTest
   [INFO] Test description:     Verify maximum response times
   [INFO] Transaction name:     getPursesRequest
   [INFO] Expected result:      Average response time <= 2000
   [INFO] Actual result:        Average response time = 1742
   [INFO] Transaction count:    600
   [INFO] Longest transactions: [24095, 23707, 22891, 18723, 16717]
   [INFO] Test result:          Pass
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Test name:            Test #5
   [INFO] Test type:            passedTransactionsTest
   [INFO] Test description:     Verify number of passed tests
   [INFO] Transaction name:     getPursesRequest
   [INFO] Expected result:      Percent of failed transactions <= 50
   [INFO] Actual result:        Percent of failed transactions = 1
   [INFO] Transaction count:    600
   [INFO] Test result:          Pass
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Test name:            Test #4
   [INFO] Test type:            nthPercRespTimeTest
   [INFO] Test description:     Verify 90th percentile
   [INFO] Transaction name:     getPursesRequest
   [INFO] Expected result:      90th percentile of transactions have 
    response time <= 8000
   [INFO] Actual result:        90th percentile of transactions have 
    response time = 2218
   [INFO] Transaction count:    600
   [INFO] Longest transactions: [24095, 23707, 22891, 18723, 16717]
   [INFO] Test result:          Pass
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Test name:            Test #3
   [INFO] Test type:            throughputTest
   [INFO] Test description:     Verify throughput
   [INFO] Transaction name:     getPursesRequest
   [INFO] Expected result:      Throughput >= 0.1 / second
   [INFO] Actual result:        Throughput = 2 / second
   [INFO] Transaction count:    600
   [ INFO] Test result:          Pass
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Test name:            Test #2
   [INFO] Test type:            maxRespTimeTest
   [INFO] Test description:     Verify maximum resp times
   [INFO] Transaction name:     getPursesRequest
   [INFO] Expected result:      Max response time <= 10000
   [INFO] Actual result:        Max response time = 24095
   [INFO] Transaction count:    600
   [INFO] Longest transactions: [24095, 23707, 22891, 18723, 16717]
   [INFO] Test result:          FAIL
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] ============= EXECUTION SUMMARY =============
   [INFO] Tests executed:    5
   [INFO] Tests passed:      4
   [INFO] Tests failed:      1
   [INFO] Tests errors:      0
   [INFO] Test set status:   FAIL
   [INFO] Execution time:    373ms
   [INFO] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='Test #1' value='1742']
   [INFO] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='Test #5' value='1']
   [INFO] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='Test #4' value='2218']
   [INFO] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='Test #3' value='2']
   [INFO] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='Test #2' value='24095']
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 05:21 min
  [INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-03T16:27:18+01:00

  [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/190M
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The lighting xml configuration file is below:

```
<testSet>

<avgRespTimeTest>
    <testName>Test #1</testName>
    <description>Verify maximum response times</description>
    <transactionName>getPursesRequest</transactionName>
    <maxAvgRespTime>2000</maxAvgRespTime>
  </avgRespTimeTest>

 <maxRespTimeTest>
    <testName>Test #2</testName>
    <description>Verify maximum resp times</description>
    <transactionName>getPursesRequest</transactionName>
    <regexp/>
    <maxAllowedRespTime>10000</maxAllowedRespTime>
 </maxRespTimeTest>


 <throughputTest>
    <testName>Test #3</testName>
    <description>Verify throughput</description>
    <transactionName>getPursesRequest</transactionName>
    <regexp/>
    <minThroughput>0.1</minThroughput>
 </throughputTest>

 <nthPercRespTimeTest>
    <testName>Test #4</testName>
    <description>Verify 90th percentile</description>
    <transactionName>getPursesRequest</transactionName>
    <regexp/>
    <percentile>90</percentile>
    <maxRespTime>8000</maxRespTime>
 </nthPercRespTimeTest>

 <passedTransactionsTest>
    <testName>Test #5</testName>
    <description>Verify number of passed tests</description>
    <transactionName>getPursesRequest</transactionName>
    <regexp/>

 <allowedPercentOfFailedTransactions>50</allowedPercentOfFailedTransactions>
 </passedTransactionsTest>
  </testSet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You response time is higher than 10 seconds according to log:

> [INFO] Test description:     Verify maximum resp
>   times
>
> Expected result:      Max response time <= 10000
>
> [INFO] Actual
>   result:        Max response time = 24095
>
> [INFO] Test result:          FAIL

If up to 30 seconds is OK, Change max response time

```
 <maxRespTimeTest>
    <testName>Test #2</testName>
    <description>Verify maximum resp times</description>
    <transactionName>getPursesRequest</transactionName>
    <regexp/>
    <maxAllowedRespTime>30000</maxAllowedRespTime>
 </maxRespTimeTest>
```

If not see how to reduce the time of your API

Comment: Yes, this worked. The failure was my understanding was that by adding a assertion that had not been met, would result in a build failure. I need to read up on the lighting plugin.